# Commucinate two arduino with each other

Tags: serial, communication

I have 2 arduino Unos where each one works properly on its own.

I try to make them communicate with each other using serial communication (TX-RX ports).

When I try to upload my code to them I get this error :

```
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 1 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 2 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 3 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 4 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 5 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 6 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 7 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 8 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 9 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
avrdude: stk500_getsync() attempt 10 of 10: not in sync: resp=0x00
An error occurred while uploading the sketch
```

what should i do to fix it ? (MY os is windows 10) thanks

Comment: Please show us how you have connected the 2 Arduinos together and the sketches you are trying to upload.

Comment: have you tried to load the sketch while the arduino has nothing connected to any of the pins?

Answer (score 1):

Pins 0 and 1 on the Arduino Uno are used for serial communication with the computer over USB, including uploading sketches. If you connect anything to those pins you can interfere with the upload process.

To communicate between the two boards using serial communication without using pins 0 and 1 you can do software serial on other pins:
https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/SoftwareSerial